# Command 'exa' not found

Tags: command-line, software-installation, path

I've installed [`exa`](https://github.com/ogham/exa) via `cargo` and added the path to my `~/.bashrc` file: `PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH` as per the post-installation instructions:

> warning: be sure to add `/root/.cargo/bin` to your PATH to be able to run the installed binaries

Despite this, when I try to run `exa` I am met with

```
Command 'exa' not found, did you mean:
...
...
...
```

When I run `printenv PATH`, `/root/.cargo/bin` appears at the *end* of the PATH, even though I had added it at the beginning.

When I run `sudo /root/.cargo/bin/exa`, the command runs fine. What is causing this/how can I get it to run properly?

Comment: Did you source your `.bashrc` after you updated it:  `. ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Can you update the post to include the value returned when one executes `printenv PATH`? My thoughts here is your PATH environment variable is not picked up from sudo (either sudoers is dropping your environment vars) or your not exporting it into the subshell.

Comment: @user1794469 Sourcing it hasn't helped.

Comment: Are you trying to run `sudo exa`? if so, remember that `sudo` typically uses its own `secure_path` rather than the `PATH` of either the target or invoking user

Comment: @steeldriver I haven't run `sudo exa`; my understanding is that it's not necessary, and that `exa` suffices. I ran as root when explicitly calling the path because the path requires superuser access.

Comment: If the path requires SU to run explicitly it will also need it for running it with a path set. Make sure that your user can execute (`x`) all the directories listed: /root/.cargo/bin. `exa` probably needs `r` and `x`

Comment: @user1794469 Sorry, can you go into a bit more detail on that? I'm basically brand-new to Linux. Additionally, when I run `sudo exa`, the command is not found either, despite it being in `PATH`. It is only when I explicitly path `exa` that it functions.

Comment: @Yehuda I'll make it an answer since it's really more than a comment I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sourcing the path isn't working it's likely a permissions issue. The `sudo` version uses a different `PATH` variable since you are running as root so while permissions aren't an issue you can't find the binary in the path.

For a user to "path through" (I'm not sure the technical term for that) a directory, they need to have "execute" permission on that directory. It shows up as an X in the 3rd position when listing the contents of the directory. So for me when I run `sudo ls -lash /root` some of the results look like this:

```
4.0K drwx------ 10 root root 4.0K Feb  3  2020 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K May 28 16:27 ..
```

The second set of letters and dashes are the permissions. The leading `d` means it's a directory, the next three letters (`rwx`) are the read, write, and execute permissions for the owner of the file. The next three (`---` in the case of `.` which is `/root` and `r-x` in the case of `..` which is `/`) are for the "group" that is associated with the file. And the final set is for everyone else.

If your permissions are anything like mine the whole root folder is only readable, writable, and passable by the root user. While you can probably get around this by adding execute to `/root` with `sudo chmod +x /root` it is generally a bad idea to mess with the permissions of the root directory/account and an especially bad idea to do it with individual commands rather than groups or other management tools.

What you likely want to do instead, is look for a way to install the binary for all users. There is likely a install method, commonly something like this:

```
sudo make install
```

But you can check the documentation, they may do something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either do one of the following:

1.
`source ~/.bashrc`

2.
`. ~/.bashrc`

3. Log out and back in.

Comment: Sure this may work in most cases; e.g. just like turn things off and on again. Even then sudoers, pam, or another system could be configured to drop a user's environment. It's best to have a user validate first with printenv $Environment_Variable_Name.

Comment: @DwightSpencer If he didn't source the init file or log out and back in, then it's not going to show up with `printenv` anyway because it hasn't been set yet. Init files like `~/.bashrc` aren't sourced until specifically done so or at login so any environment variables in them aren't going to be set just by putting them into the file(s).

Comment: that may be the case 99.9% of the time but not my point. Its best to teach a user how to debug instead of throwing a random answer out without knowing the root issue.

Also looking over the comments from OP; "Sourcing it hasn't helped" hints that its sudo dropping the environment. So once again its back to teach the user to fish not give him a sardine.

Comment: @DwightSpencer What are you even on about here? You stated to have him use `printenv` and I've already explained why that isn't going to work. This isn't something that happens 99% of the time. It happens 100% of the time as that's the way that it's designed to work. If sourcing it didn't work, then it's up to him to provide information on what he did as there isn't any reason that it wouldn't work if being done properly. Your `printenv` business doesn't apply here.